# Drop down menu not fully overlapping menu option. Z-index settings

Tags: html, css, menu, z-index

I have expanded the menus so you can see the overlapping menus on http://ocart.site/opencart/

Do you know which Z-index settings to apply so when you hover over Desktops and the menu drops down. You cannot see the Components menu title within the dropdown.

Comment: Create JSfiddle or post your code

Comment: `opacity` changes stacking context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make some changes to your stylesheet.

After viewing the link and inspecting the code, i found you need to do the following:

Remove the z-index property from these styles:

```
#menu > ul > li
```

AND

```
#menu > ul > li > a
```

You do not need to declare z-index for either of these elements.

Then you need to set a z-index of 1 to the following like so:

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Once you have done that you will be able to see the dropdown menu over the menu titles and it won't be obscured.

Answer (score 1):

change the following css codes in your `stylesheet`

remove the `position:relative;` from `#menu > ul > li` `line No 338`

```
#menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 5px 5px 0;
  /* position: relative; */ /* Remove this property */
  z-index: 0;
}
```

and set `z-index:10` to `#menu > ul > li > div` `line No 364`

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
 z-index:10;
}
```